# Page loading incorrectly when Browser Mode: IE7 and Document Mode: IE7 standards

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have an issue that I have spent a lot of time searching for a solution for.

My page renders fine in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, IE8/9/10 however after pressing F12 in IE and then selecting 'Browser Mode: IE7', the 'Document Mode' automatically sets to 'IE7 standards' and my page render breaks. If I change the 'Document Mode' to anything other than 'IE7 standards' including 'quirks mode' or 'standards' then my page renders correctly.

I have noticed that the 'sizset' and 'sizcache' attributes get dynamically applied to certain HTML elements, again when Browser Mode: IE7 and Document Mode: IE7 standards.

My doctype is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I have tried adding the following to i) the  and ii) below the doctype but again no good news: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

Any ideas please?

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't using F12 to change that setting override the meta tag?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"my page render breaks"*?

Comment: -I'm not sure (your first point)

Comment: My page breaks as if the clearfix class isn't working working e.g. backgrounds not extended to the full height

Comment: If you meant that your layout is all messed up, that's just how bad off IE7's html/css support was back then (8 years ago!). If you want to support it, the best way to start is by ensuring all of your html/css passes validation, then you will additionally have to add IE7 specific styles to fix what's left.

Comment: I built the content for a CMS page, in a text editor locally before uploading to the CMS. My code validates 100% and looks as it should in FF,Chrome,Safari, IE7/8/9/10. When the page containing my code is loaded, there is also jQuery code (on other parts of the page). It seems that this is connected to the added sizset and sizcache attributes which are giving me the problems in IE7 only

Comment: Ie7 is the only one that should have sizset and sizcache, it's used for nth-child support. That's likely unrelated to your issue.